# Plotly Stacked Bar Chart text annotation issue

Tags: python, plotly, stacked-chart

So, I have this simplified data frame and I'm using `plotly.graph_objects` to plot a stacked bar chart with text annotations.
I got the text as I wanted from the Salary column but I can't get the same for the Age column where the values are significantly lower. I would like these annotations to be the same size and on top of each bar.
How can I get the text annotations to be visible for the Age column as well?

Please find my code below:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Jack'],
        'Age':[18, 21, 19],
        'Salary':[500, 700, 900]}
df_new=pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x = df_new["Name"],
                       y = df_new["Age"],name='Age',text=df_new["Age"],
                       textposition='outside'))
fig.add_bar(x = df_new["Name"],
            y = df_new["Salary"],name='Salary',text=df_new["Salary"],
            textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',
                  title = 'Age - Salary',
                  xaxis_title="Name",
                  yaxis_title="Age / Salary")
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to choose from 2 possible solutions. First of all, by using the `barmode = stack` argument, you are stacking and thus summing the values of age and salary. The height of bars will be `age + salary`, such that the height of Tom's bar will be `500 + 18 = 518`. I'd advise against this, as the height should reflect the callout value in my opinion.

---

**Solution 1 - grouped bars**

This solution is based on changing the barmode to `barmode = group`. This will make two separate bars, which have their own callout and heights reflecting their values.
I've also added the `width` argument to make prettier aspect ratios.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_bar(x = df_new["Name"],
            y = df_new["Age"],name='Age',text=df_new["Age"],
            width = [0.3]*len(df_new),
            )

fig.add_bar(x = df_new["Name"],
            y = df_new["Salary"],name='Salary',text=df_new["Salary"],
            width = [0.3]*len(df_new)
            )
fig.update_layout(barmode='group',
                  title = 'Age - Salary',
                  xaxis_title="Name",
                  yaxis_title="Age / Salary"
                  )
fig.update_traces(
    textposition='outside'
)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,1000])
```

---

**Solution 2 - add secondary y-axis**

I prefer this solution, as the relative size of the two categories can each be scaled to their own domain; which makes the chart a lot more readable. This uses `make_subplots` to create two axes and the `secondary_y` argument. I've made both bars visible by playing around with the widths and ranges of the axes.

Based on the data you'd have to manually rescale to your liking. You could also incorporate `opacity` for look-through bars, but you'd still have the risk of overlapping data callouts.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_bar(
    x=df_new["Name"],
    y=df_new["Age"],
    name="Age",
    text=df_new["Age"],
    width=[0.3] * len(df_new),
    secondary_y=True,
    textposition="outside"
)
fig.add_bar(
    x=df_new["Name"],
    y=df_new["Salary"],
    name="Salary",
    text=df_new["Salary"],
    width=[0.5] * len(df_new),
    secondary_y=False,
    textposition="outside"
)

fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1000], title='Salary', secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 45], title='Age', secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(title="Age and Salary", xaxis_title="Name")
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Seth for a very comprehensive answer. I prefer solution 2.
Although I had already used the secondary y-axis I did not remember to use it in this case. Opacity is also a nice option.